# Variable is not getting stored after submitting the form

Tags: php, html, sql, forms

Sorry if the Title doesn't make any sense.
So, my code is as follows:

```
<?php
            $conn=new mysqli("localhost","root","aman8blue","users");
            $conn->connect_error;
            $querynor= mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM userinfo");
            $nor=mysqli_num_rows($querynor);
            for($i=1; $i<=$nor; $i++) {
?>

<form method='post'>
    <label class='switch'><input type='checkbox' name='check' value=1 onChange='this.form.submit()'><span class='slider_round'></span></label>
</form>

<?php

$status = 0;

if(isset($_POST['check'])) {
    $status=1;
}


if($status==1) {
    echo "WORKING!";
}
else {
    echo "NOPE!";
}
}
?>
```

But no matter what, even if I tick the checkbox, it shows "WORKING!". I can't understand where am I wrong.

(Sorry the previous one was incomplete)

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: your input's missing attribute name, add `name='check'` to your input, the `$_POST['check']` get the value of the input with the `name=check`, not the `id`

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. The code behaves as expected when I test it.

Comment: i dont see a submit button, so i asume it's an ajax call, am i correct? Post then the ajax call data. --- Edit --- oops `this.form.submit()` never mind my comment

Comment: U dont see submit button but there is form.submit in checkbox.

Comment: Sorry but this is the whole code

Comment: Wait ... you add your code after? change the order and put php processing code above your html output. Maybe not the solution to your problem, however if you reuse that status for something else after this checkbox, it might be handy to have that variable ready

Comment: Tell me what I need to edit :/

Comment: Actualy this code will always Show WORKING. Cause form will only be submitted if u click checkbox

Comment: But it should display Working when the checkbox is ticked and Nope when its not

Comment: But u dont save checked state, so it will always be WORKING as i described. 
Change label line to this <label class='switch'><input type='checkbox' name ='check' id='check' value=1 onChange='this.form.submit()' <?php echo (isset($_POST['check']) ?  'checked':''); ?>><span class='slider_round'></span></label>

Comment: then your else statement is in wrong place, it should be on if(isset($_POST['check'])) , not    if($status==1)

Comment: Michal Szalapski, I edited it like yours but now if we untick one box all of them show the effect and vice-versa.

Comment: My Problem is not solved YET

Comment: Cause u need to do unique inputs if u want to recognize them for example by id from database. Like <label class='switch'><input type='checkbox' name ='check[0]' id='check' value=1 onChange='this.form.submit()' <?php echo (isset($_POST['check'][0]) ?  'checked':''); ?>><span class='slider_round'></span></label>

Comment: Also I preffer to put form outside the iteration loop

Comment: Man! it doesn't seem to work, the same result. Can you Please elaborate in answers, it would be of great help.

Comment: I need form inside the loop because I need multiple input boxes

Comment: Do u have ID row in database?

Comment: Yes I do Surely

Answer (score 0):

add

```
name="check"
```

in your input since post is looking for name attribute and you don't have one

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "xxxx", "users");
$conn->connect_error;
$querynor = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM userinfo");
$nor = mysqli_num_rows($querynor);

echo '<form method=\'post\'>';
for ($i = 1; $i <= $nor; $i++)
    {
    ?>
        <label class='switch'><input type='checkbox' name='check[<?php echo $nor[$i]['id']; ?>]' value=1 onChange='this.form.submit()' <?php echo (isset($_POST['check'][$nor[$i]['id']]) ? 'checked':''); ?>>
            <span class='slider_round'></span>
        </label>
    <?php
    }
echo '</form>';
?>
```

As the answer to the comment.

Comment: Could you please edit this answer and explain to me here! It would be of great help.